# Arduino Mega upload issue

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, uploading, avrdude

I have made my own version of an Arduino Mega and I am encountering some issues. Whenever I try to upload any sketch to the Mega, I get the following error message:

avrdude: stk500v2 ReceiveMessage(): timeout

I can upload just fine to the 16u2 as well as the 2560 using ICSP and Nick Gammons Atmega_Board_Programmer sketch. I have the correct board and COM port selected, and the cable, computer, and USB(2.0) port can upload to other Arduino boards just fine.

I have had some other troubles with the board that have been solved, but this issue remains. Please see [my Arduino forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=560968.0) for more details on these issues.

My current guess is that there may some sort of issue with the transmission lines between the 16u2 and the 2560. [Here is a picture of the pcb traces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDvvi.jpg). Can anyone look them over to see if there are issues with the traces?

If the traces seem fine, can anyone think of another reason why the upload does not work?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81204/discussion-on-question-by-bos1714-arduino-mega-upload-issue).

Answer (score 0):

So as of right now the problem has been solved. The issue was that the decoupling capacitor on the reset line near the 2560 was designed to be a 22pF capacitor, but I had put a 100nF capacitor, which increases the time constant by a factor of 5000, prohibiting the auto-reset circuitry from operating correctly. Removing the 100nF and putting in the 22pF seems to have solved the issue of only being able to upload once after burning the bootloader.

Thank you everyone for your support.

Comment: Can you elaborate? A decoupling capacitor is usually between Vcc and Gnd, so it wouldn't be "on the reset line". The capacitor *in series* with Reset (and usually going to RTS on the FTDI header) should work fine as 100nF. If you really have a decoupling capacitor on Reset (between Reset and Gnd) then you shouldn't have it.

Comment: [Example schematic](https://www.gammon.com.au/images/Wire_Wrapped_Atmega132_e.png), which has always worked for me (this is the Atmega328P but it is the same concept).

Comment: Sorry for delay. For the reset connection between the 16u2 and the 2560, I have a 10k pull-down resistor on the 16u2 side, then a 100nF capacitor in series from the 16u2 to the 2560, a 10k pullup resistor on the 2560 side, and a 22pF shunt capacitor (shunt is a better word than decoupling). The shunt capacitor was a 100nF and that was causing the auto-reset to not work correctly.

Comment: Whatever word you use, you don't need that capacitor between Reset and ground. The schematic I linked to above shows a **diode** between Reset and Vcc which should suppress any inadvertent pulses which might put it into high-voltage programming mode, but that probably won't be required unless you have problems with it not resetting.

Comment: So there are some issues. I made three boards. One of them works correctly, the other two do not. I can manually program each chip (16u2 and 2560) with FLIP, Arduino as ISP, and your board programmer sketch. The circuitry is the same in each of the three boards. I have checked the resonators of each chip and they are functioning at 16MHz. Is the capacitor in question the culprit? The capacitor is populated on genuine Mega boards so I made sure to have it in mine. I have also noticed that when I program the blink sketch to the 2560 using ArduinoISP, The LED will stay on for 1s and off for 0.5s

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. The schematic has the 22 pF capacitor on the main chip but not on the Atmega16U2. On my schematic I see that PD7 on the Atmega16U2 goes to Reset on the Atmega2560 via the 100 nF capacitor. I would be more doubtful of the 100 nF capacitor than the 22 pF capacitor.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the 100nF series capacitor is to only allow a low to high or high to low signal transition from the 16u2 to the 2560 and that a capacitor with too low or too high capacitance can adversely affect the time constant, causing the 2560 to reset before or after the data is ready to be sent?

Comment: What data? It's purpose is to allow RTS to be pulled low (and stay low) by the USB interface. Initially that will activate Reset because it will go low temporarily, but then the pull-up resistor on Reset will charge the capacitor again, taking Reset high, and allowing the chip to run. I don't think the value is particularly critical. Too low, and the Reset pulse could be too short. Too high and the bootloader data will be sent while the processor is still reset. Still, the bootloader protocol should handle anything other than an egregiously long time.

Comment: Yes the line is to control the auto reset and the RC circuit timing can adversely effect the bootloader not starting on time or ending too quickly, but yes only with a drastic difference. The data is sent over the UART lines, but the reset line lets the 2560 reset and run the bootloader, which looks for the data. If the bootloader ends too quickly the, 16u2 will spit out the ReceiveMessage timout error since no data is being received since the bootloader on the 2560 is done with its process(es)